# Year Calculation in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
StartDate = 01/01/2013 
EndDate = 12/31/2019
```

I need to get the year column like `'2013-14' , '2014-15' , 2015-16` and so on.

**For example**, the 2013-14 year should contains date details from Jun 2013 to May 2014. Like wise i need to get the year upto End date. Please help me out.

**concat(datepart(YY,StartDate ),'-', RIGHT(YEAR(StartDate ),2) + 1)**

I used the above format. i can get the output as 2013-14. But i need to specify the range of month for splitting years.

Regards,
Vanmathi

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(StartDate, 'yyyy-MM'),
    FORMAT(EndDate, 'yyyy-MM')
```

Read all about the `FORMAT` function on the [official MSDN documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a user defined function to slice up the date and then text concatenation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSlicedYear(@TheDate date)
RETURNS varchar(7)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SlicedYear varchar(7)  
    IF DATEPART(month, @TheDate) < 6
        SELECT @SlicedYear = (DATEPART(year, @TheDate) -1 ) +"-"+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(@TheDate) As varchar(4)),2)
    ELSE
        SELECT @SlicedYear = DATEPART(year, @TheDate) +"-"+ RIGHT(CAST((YEAR(@TheDate) +1) As varchar(4)),2)
    RETURN @SlicedYear
END
```

Then something like this to Order (or group).

```
 SELECT SomeField, GetSlicedYear(SomeDate) FROM SomeTable ORDER BY GetSlicedYear(SomeDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below select statement -

```
select FORMAT(StartDate , 'yyyy') + '-' + FORMAT(EndDate , 'yyyy')
```